# How to use v-model with inLine object

Tags: object, vue.js, inline, v-model

i have a custom component with 2 inputs let say `date_on` and `date_off`
i want to bind that component to current object .
note i don't want to use any computed value or function to keep using it on different component without adding extra methods.

using computed variable it works fine but using `inLine` object it gives me this error :

> 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS

```js
data() {
  return {
    dateOn1: '',
    dateOff1: '',
    dateOn2: '',
    daeOff2: ''
  }
},
computed:{
  dates:{
    get(){
       return {dt_on:this.dt_on1,dt_off:this.dt_off1};
    }
    set(value){
      this.dt_on1 = value.dt_on;
      this.dt_off1= value.dt_off;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <my-dates  v-model="{dateOn:dateOn1,dateOff:dateOff1 }"></my-dates>
    <my-dates  v-model="{dateOn:dateOn2,dateOff:dateOff2 }"></my-dates>
    <my-dates  v-model="dates"></my-dates> <!-- work fine  -->
</template>
```

Comment: I think you should to use `:value` and `@input` instead of `v-model`

Comment: it work but the code is ugly `code
              <my-dates                                                                   
                       :value="{dt_on:dt_on1,dt_off:dt_off1}"                   
                       @input="(v)=>{dt_on1=v.dt_on;dt_off1=v.dt_off}">
             </my-dates>
            `